# How to check and fix project Python path and configuration?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote this code in my machine learning project using Python in Google Colab

Gui_stuff

```
root = Tk()
root.configure(background='blue')
```

This causes the following TclError:

```
TclError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-1cbd6c991aed> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 root = Tk()
      3 root.configure(background='blue')

/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   2021                 baseName = baseName + ext
   2022         interactive = 0
-> 2023         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   2024         if useTk:
   2025             self._loadtk()

TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I believe this is a Python path and configuration problem, but how do I fix it so that it will work.

Comment: Run the command in Ubuntu terminal:
`export DISPLAY=:0` .Hope, this may solve your issue.

Comment: You can run it by using ngrok to expose your instance to the Internet and then creating a VNC server.

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab is a browser based environment, built on top of Jupyter. 
In runs "in the cloud". This basically means that your code is running on a google server somewhere.

Such an environment is not suitable for running `tkinter`-based Python scripts. You should run those locally on your own computer.